# Jump certain number of cells when dragging formula down on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to create a fórmula that when it is dragged down it jumps a certain pre defined number of cells. For example, I have this column:

[image]

However I want a formula that when I drag down it jumps 6 rows, something like =A(1+6) in the second row and so on, so it gets to look like this:

[image]

Is there a "pythonic" way to do that or I need to create some regexextract in a new column + query formula getting only non blank cells?

Example sheet in this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RYzX31i8sBFROwFrQGql_eZ6tPu69KDesqzQ3hSj028/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in B2

```
=offset($A$1;5*row(A2)-10;)
```

Answer (score 0):

try instead:

```
=QUERY(A1:A; "skipping 5"; 0)
```

[image]